# How to scroll to a particular div in Chrome within a tinymce?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, tinymce, scrollview

I've a tinymce editor. When the of the editor is longer than the height of the page, scrolling doesn't work correctly in Chrome. Here is what I did so far.

I highlight a word using a span, the span has id and class. Soemthing like this

Once the word is highlighted, I scroll to the span, using it's ID, like this:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getDoc().getElementById('highlight').scrollIntoView();
```

This works correctly in Firefox, but on Chrome, it just keeps jumping up and down. As the words at the bottom of the page are highlighted, sometimes the view goes back up! Is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: works fine in my chrome v. 47.0.2526.106 m

Comment: @Thariama - did you change anything? is it the same code that works for you?

Comment: yes, it is the same code